# Deploy Specific SPARK Version On a Cluster

Tags: deployment, jar, dependencies, cluster-computing, spark-submit

On my current project, I tried to deploy a 2.2 version of SPARK where on the cluster a 2.1 version is available. I looked in the SPARK documentation the way to deploy specific dependencies on a cluster which led me to use the following spark-submit:

```
    spark-submit --master yarn --class MainMethodSparkApp --conf spark.driver.extraClassPath=localPath-to-jar-with-ependencies
   --conf spark.executor.extraClassPath=localPath-to-jar-with-dependencies --conf spark.jars=hdfsPath-jar-with-dependencies --queue queueName --deploy-mode cluster 
   --driver-memory xx --num-executors xx --executor-memory xx --executor-core xx
```

The driver and executors are set using the jar with the dependencies. However, I am still getting a No.Such.Method.Exception;
The SPARK documentation is a bit unclear as to which options to use to successfully deploy specific dependencies. What am I missing?
Any suggestions are welcomed.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to make it work. Here is what I did: the necessary components are:
--conf spark.driver.extraClassPath=/local-path-of-each-datanode/spark-with-depencies.jar
--conf spark.executor.extraClassPath=/local-path-of-each-datanode/spark-with-depencies.jar
The jar contains all the dependencies of the alternative version of Spark. Also make sure to include Yarn/Hadoop dependencies since it must must be deployed on a Yarn/Hadoop cluster

spark-submit --master yarn --class MainMethodSparkApp --conf spark.driver.extraClassPath=localPath-to-jar-with-ependencies
--conf spark.executor.extraClassPath=localPath-to-jar-with-dependencies --queue queueName --deploy-mode cluster
--driver-memory xx --num-executors xx --executor-memory xx --executor-core xx
/local-path-on-edgeNode/smalljar.jar

The smalljar.jar is the jar launching the application and doesn't include dependencies
I noticed that the fat-jar must be deployed on each and every node.